# Maven with Ant : exec Command line

Tags: java, maven, ant

I want to retrieve the serial number of my computer by running ant task in `pom.xml`.

```
<profile>
        <id>generate-license</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <exec executable="wmic bios get serialnumber"
                                          resultproperty="serialNumber"
                                          failonerror="false" />
                                    <echo message="Serial number: ${serialNumber}" />
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I execute maven at compile phase and here is the result:

> [WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
>   [INFO] Executing tasks

main:

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                      [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                      [INFO] Total time: 1:48.264s
>   [INFO] Finished at: Wed May 27 10:17:57 GMT+01:00 2015
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/121M
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                      [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) on
>   project runner: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed:
>   java.io.IOExcept ion: Cannot run program "wmic bios get serialnumber":
>   CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable
>   [ERROR] around Ant part ...... @
>   4:100 in C:\xxx\yyy\target\antrun\build-main.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try the arguments using the following syntax please?

```
<exec executable="wmic" resultproperty="serialNumber" failonerror="false">
      <arg value="bios" />
      <arg value="get" />
      <arg value="serialnumber" />
</exec>
```

Comment: or as a single like <arg value="bios get serialnumber" />, both should work